# WPF Graph Layout Component

Tags: .net, wpf, layout, graph, components

Does anyone know of or even better.. can wholeheartedly recommend a WPF graph layout component (Microsoft Research had [GLEE](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/f1303e46-965f-401a-87c3-34e1331d32c5/default.aspx) a while back but it hasn't been updated after 1.0 since 2007 and isn't WPF etc) as seen e.g. in the screenshot below?

I've seen *yFiles WPF* and *Lasalle's AddFlow for WPF*, but are there any alternatives?

[RedGate Ants Memory Profiler as example http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/screenshot_gallery/Class_Explorer.gif](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/screenshot_gallery/Class_Explorer.gif)

(c) Screenshot: [RedGate Ants Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_memory_profiler/index.htm)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/.
I started a project, today, using MSAGL, but I would rather use WPF for the UI.

From the site:

> - Can use all kinds of algorithms (layout, overlap removal, edge,
>     highlight)
> - Vertex dragging supported
> - Templates for vertices and edges supported
> - Mutable graph -> automatic relayout after the graph changes (burst mode:
>     lot of modification but only 1
>     relayout)
> - Async layout (background thread) supported
> - Position changes are animated!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look demos at http://www.goxam.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [GraphX for .NET PRO](http://graphx.pro). We have much to offer in both free and commercial versions: many customizable layouts, edge routing, graph filters and advanced styles for everything.

We're the successor of the now discontinued graphsharp.